# How to put a simple img logo into app in Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to put a logo for my application in sencha, I have a panel so far and the rest of the app, I would like to put a logo into the app now. I put an img element into it but I need the logo to sit in the panel at the top of the page, is there anyway to do this.

Heres my my panel code

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'Qvidi'
    },
]
```

Comment: Or i can basically put it anywhere at the top, it must just look like a properly formatted logo at the top right

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Img

Comment: ext.img can help you, or also you can print the img directly in your html

Answer (score 0):

```
{
     xtype: 'image',
     height: 25,
     margin: 2,
     width: 94,
     src: 'resources/images/logo.png'
}
```

put this in your items array to have your logo img in a component.
Usually i put it on the bottom right corner on my panel